# How do I add a custom augmentation using tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Currently, there is no support for Cutout image augmentation during the preprocessing step using the TensorFlow object detection API.

My question is:

***1. How can I add a custom augmentation(Cutout in this case) to the TensorFlow object detection preprocessor?***

I tried to follow:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/ec4b78f3e7030184b255099c369c52e9b404d71f

After following that pull request and running `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` in the protoc directory

and attempting to use the cutout augmentation I implemented during the training of an object detector, I get the following error:

```
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 140:5 : Message type "object_detection.protos.PreprocessingStep" has no field named "CutOut".
```

Also, for the implementation of Cutout, I'm using https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/cutout

Any help and guidance are very much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not that experienced in Tensorflow's object detection API, but I think you can add an augmentation called "random_black_patches", that is similar to cutout. You can see it in the proto [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto#L25).

If you see the arguments, you can see that you control the number, probability and aspect ratio of the patches.

I used it in my `pipeline.config` as follows:

```
train_config {
  batch_size: 4
  data_augmentation_options{
    random_black_patches {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested random_black_patches and it seems to produce the same results as Cutout.

Comment: glad it worked :) could you please accept my awnser then?